# Invalid Data Binding SAP UI5 BAR CHARTVIZ Chart

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to display a bar chart on click of Go button on selection screen.

I am getting invalid data binding in place of VIZ Chart.

I have attached the error message which I am getting. I have attached my XML view and its controller logic as well.

[image]

```js
sap.ui.controller("znwpm_charts_dash.Charts", {

/**
* Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
* Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
* @memberOf znwpm_charts_dash.Charts
*/
 onInit: function() {
  var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame");
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel");
  var oResourceModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
   bundleName :"znwpm_charts_dash/i18n/i18n",
   async :true
  });
  
   var oViewInternalModel = this.getView().getModel('viewInternalModel');
   if(!oViewInternalModel){
    oViewInternalModel =  new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(); 
    oViewInternalModel.setProperty("/filters", []);
       this.getView().setModel(oViewInternalModel, 'viewInternalModel')};  

  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oResourceModel , "i18n");
//  
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.Filter" );
  if(!oVizFrame){
   
  }else{
   
  oVizFrame.setVisible(false); 
  oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
   title:{
    text : "NWPM"
   }
   });   } 
 },
 
 
 onSearch:function(evt){

  this.aFilters = [];
  var button = evt.getSource();
  var eDock = sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock;
    
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");
  var startDate = this.getView().byId("startDateId").getValue();
  
  if(!startDate){
   sap.m.MessageToast.show("Start Date is required Field" ,{
   duration:4000,
   width :"25em",
   my: eDock.CenterCenter,
   at: eDock.CenterCenter,
   of: window,
   offset:"20"
   
  })  ;
   
  }else{
  
   var endDate = this.getView().byId("endDateId").getValue();
   
   if(!endDate){
    sap.m.MessageToast.show("End Date is required Field" ,{
    duration:4000,
    width :"25em",
    my: eDock.CenterCenter,
    at: eDock.CenterCenter,
    of: window,
    offset:"20"
    
   })  ;   
   
   
  }else{
   
   this.__applyFilters();    
   
   
  };
   
  };
   
 },
 
 __applyFilters:function(){
  var oView = this.getView();
  var filterModel = this.getView().getModel('viewInternalModel').getProperty("/filters");
  this.__setDefaultFilters();
  this.__oDataCall();
 }, 
 

 
 __setDefaultFilters:function(){
   this._filterSetTemp('DateFrom', this.getView().byId("startDateId").getValue());
   this._filterSetTemp('DateTo', this.getView().byId("endDateId").getValue());
 },
 
 _filterSetTemp:function(sPropertyName, oInputValue){
 
  if(!this.aFilters){  
   this.aFilters = [];
   var aFilters = []; 
  }   
  var oViewInternalModel = this.getView().getModel('viewInternalModel');
  var aFilter = oViewInternalModel.getProperty("/filters");
  aFilter[sPropertyName] = oInputValue;
  oViewInternalModel.refresh();   
  this.aFilters.push( new sap.ui.model.Filter(sPropertyName, sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oInputValue ) );
 },
 
 __oDataCall:function(){
  var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame");
  var sUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZIMM_INTERFACE_DASH_SRV";  
  var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sUrl ,true); 
  var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();   
  oItemsFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter(this.aFilters, true);       
  var oView = this.getView();   
  oBusy = sap.ui.getCore().byId("busyID");
  if(!oBusy){
   var oBusy = new sap.m.BusyDialog("busyID",{
    text :"Fetching Data" 
  });
  } 
  
  oBusy.open();
  
        oDataModel.read("/ChartsSet",{
          filters:[oItemsFilters], 
            success:function(oData,response){
             debugger;
                  oJsonModel.setData(oData);
                  oVizFrame.setModel(oJsonModel);  
                  oVizFrame.setVisible(true);
                  oView.setModel(oJsonModel );
                  sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oJsonModel);
                  
                  oBusy.close();
                  
            },
            error:function(err){
             oBusy.close();
            }
     });
        
 }, 
 
 selectData:function(evt){
  debugger;
  var onClick = evt.getParameters('data').data[0].data["Functional Area"];
  var oApp = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idApp");
  oApp.to("idTable");
 }, 

/**
* Similar to onAfterRendering, but this hook is invoked before the controller's View is re-rendered
* (NOT before the first rendering! onInit() is used for that one!).
* @memberOf znwpm_charts_dash.Charts
*/
// onBeforeRendering: function() {
//
// },

/**
* Called when the View has been rendered (so its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the HTML could be done here.
* This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls get after being rendered.
* @memberOf znwpm_charts_dash.Charts
*/
// onAfterRendering: function() {
//
// },

/**
* Called when the Controller is destroyed. Use this one to free resources and finalize activities.
* @memberOf znwpm_charts_dash.Charts
*/
// onExit: function() {
//
// }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

  <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m ,sap.viz"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    ata-sap-ui-preload="async"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
  </script>
  <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

  <script>
    sap.ui.localResources("znwpm_charts_dash");
    var app = new sap.m.App("idApp",{initialPage:"idCharts1"});
    var page = sap.ui.view({id:"idCharts1", viewName:"znwpm_charts_dash.Charts", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
    app.addPage(page);
    
    var page2 = sap.ui.view({id:"idTable", viewName:"znwpm_charts_dash.Table", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
    app.addPage(page2);
    
    app.placeAt("content");
  </script>

 </head>
 <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
 
  <div id="content"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described. Could you therefore try to remove all code in your example that is (most probable) not related to your problem?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please replace the image of XML with the XML in text format.